# find the number of sequences of length $n$ over $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ in which the difference between any two consecutive members is $1$ or $-1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Question:

> Find the number of series of length-$n$ over $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ where the difference between any two consecutive members is $1$ or $-1$

Below are my workings. I'm stuck because I don't understand how I can make the recursion.

> Let $a_n$ be the number of $n$-length series.
>
> Let $a_n^k$ be the number of $n$-length series such that the first element is $k$.
>
> We have that $a_n=a_n^0+a_n^1+a_n^2+a_n^3+a_n^4$
>
> If the series starts with $0$, then the next element must be $1$, and we have that $a_n^0=a_{n-1}^1$
>
> If the series starts with $1$, then the next element must be $2$ or $0$, and we have that $a_n^1=a^2_{n-1}+a^0_{n-1}$
>
> If the series starts with $2$, then the next element must be $3$ or $1$, and we have that $a_n^2=a^3_{n-1}+a^1_{n-1}$

There is an similar answer to this but not in the same way that my college requires.

Comment: The series cannot start with $0$, can it ? You said it must be in $\lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace$

Comment: sorry its an edit mistake it can start with 0 its over {0,1,2,3,4}